# Problemas Python con archivos y librerías no encontradas

Tags: python

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.
```

Es el mensaje de error que me sale en la terminal de VS Code en un archivo de Python.
Scipy está instalado, lo he comprobado con el comando `pip list` en la terminal de Anaconda. El problema no es nuevo, anteriormente no me encontraba el archivo versiones.py (que es en el que estoy experimentado los fallos) también decir que el primer archivo que guarde de VS Code se guardo en la carpeta donde busca los archivos ahora pero desde que instale Anaconda y las librerías se guardan en otra carpeta ( que es en la que no los encuentra). Me imagino que el fallo es parecido pero la librería no se como moverla en la carpeta especifica, y en la carpeta especifica tengo un archivo que no reconozco llamado: STR, y la fecha de creación creo que es de cuando instale Anaconda y las librerías. debe de ser un fallo de novato pero me estoy leyendo un libro de Machine Learning y no puedo avanzar los ejercicios hasta que solucione esto. Saludos y muchas gracias!

Comment: Tenes 2 o mas versiones de Python instaladas?

Comment: Usa la terminal de vscode, no la de anaconda.

Comment: @Dante S. solo tengo Python 3.10.5 aunque la instale varias veces. Pero las rutas son las dos en el mismo disco duro el C:.

Comment: @ChemaCortes en la terminal de VS Code no me sale instalada ninguna librería.

Comment: Pues ese es el problema. Configura el intérprete de python en vscode. Sigue las instrucciones de la documentación: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_select-a-python-interpreter

Comment: Ok @ChemaCortes, muchas gracias por la ayuda... Miraré las instrucciones.